# Azure DevOps Pipelines Expressions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-extensions, azure-pipelines-decorator

Goal is to condition a task custom extension based on which task is used in pipeline. For that we want to use [pipelines decorators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops)

For example, if any user is using Powershell task in their pipelines, we want to execute our task with decorators.

But we can figure out how to make it works.

Yaml :

```
 steps:
 - ${{ if and(eq(resources.repositories['self'].ref, r esources.repositories['self'].defaultBranch), not(containsValue(job.steps.*.task.id, 'd9bafed4-0b18-4f58-968d-86655b4d2ce9'))) }}:
   - script: dir
     displayName: 'Run my script (injected from decorator)'
```

*Directly from Microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-pipeline-decorator?view=azure-devops#my-decoratoryml-final-version)*

Inside Azure DevOps Pipelines, visual editor brings this error :

```
 Unexpected property ${{ if containsValue(job.steps.*.task.id, '1c524b9b-9f4d-4897-8f1e-6ec33271d75c') }}
```

The first property must be task

And at runtime :

[image: error]

We also tried with `condition()` :

```
condition: |
    and
    (
      eq(dependencies.A.result, 'Succeeded'),
      containsValue(dependencies.A.steps.*.task.id, '1c524b9b-9f4d-4897-8f1e-6ec33271d75c')
    )
```

But we can't find correct syntax, object content is null :

[image: object_null]

Anyone know how to retrieve task id and use it to condition any further task ?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/pipeline-decorator-context?view=azure-devops) in your **Decorator YAML file**, not the pipeline azure-pipelines.yml file. To get started with Pipeline Decorators, you need to follow the following steps:

- Create an extension file. This defines the type of extension, as well
  as the packaged files.
- Create a YAML file. This file contains the steps you want to execute
  for each pipeline.
- Create an HTML file. This will be displayed when a user views your
  extension in the Marketplace.
- Package the extension. This creates a .VSIX file you will use to
  register your extension.
- Register your extension. This involves uploading your file to the
  Azure DevOps Marketplace and making it available to your Azure DevOps
  Organization.
- Add the extension to your org. This allows the extension to be
  applied to your pipelines.

You cam get more details from the following blog:

https://soltisweb.com/blog/detail/2019-11-07-simplifying-azure-devops-pipelines-with

Comment: Thank you. I realized context is different between pipeline and decorator. Putting same pipeline yaml content in yaml decorator worked!. Anyway your blog is clear and detailed.

Comment: I tried but as I have less than 15 reputation, it's recorded but not displayed